# Use MonadRef to implement MonadCont

Tags: haskell, continuations, delimited-continuations

There is a well known issue that [we cannot use `forall` types in the `Cont` return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178919/how-to-make-callcc-more-dynamic/7180154#7180154).

However it should be OK to have the following definition:

```
class Monad m => MonadCont' m where
    callCC' :: ((a -> forall b. m b) -> m a) -> m a
    shift :: (forall r.(a -> m r) -> m r) -> m a
    reset :: m a -> m a
```

and then find an instance that makes sense. In [this paper](http://www.carlssonia.org/ogi/mdo-callcc.pdf) the author claimed that we can implement `MonadFix` on top of `ContT r m` providing that `m` implemented `MonadFix` and `MonadRef`. But I think if we do have a `MonadRef` we can actually implement `callCC'` above like the following:

```
--satisfy law: mzero >>= f === mzero
class Monad m => MonadZero m where
    mzero :: m a

instance (MonadZero m, MonadRef r m) => MonadCont' m where
    callCC' k = do
        ref <- newRef Nothing
        v <- k (\a -> writeRef ref (Just a) >> mzero)
        r <- readRef ref
        return $ maybe v id r
    shift = ...
    reset = ...
```

(Unfortunately I am not familiar with the semantic of `shift` and `reset` so I didn't provide implementations for them)

This implementation seems OK for me. Intuitively, when `callCC'` being called, we feed `k` which a function that its own effect is always fail (although we are not able to provide a value of arbitrary type `b`, but we can always provide `mzero` of type `m b` and according to the law it should effectively stop all further effects being computed), and it captures the received value as the final result of `callCC'`.

So my question is:

Is this implementation works as expected for an ideal `callCC`? Can we implement `shift` and `reset` with proper semantic as well?

In addition to the above, I want to know:

To ensure the proper behaviour we have to assume some property of `MonadRef`. So what would the laws a `MonadRef` to have in order to make the above implementation behave as expected?

**UPDATE**

It turn out that the above naive implementation is not good enough. To make it satisfy "Continuation current"

```
callCC $\k -> k m === callCC $ const m === m
```

We have to adjust the implementation to

```
instance (MonadPlus m, MonadRef r m) => MonadCont' m where
    callCC' k = do 
       ref <- newRef mzero
       mplus (k $ \a -> writeRef ref (return a) >> mzero) (join (readRef ref))
```

In other words, the original `MonadZero` is not enough, we have to be able to combind a `mzero` value with a normal computation without cancelling the whole computation.

**The above does not answer the question, it is just adjusted as the original attempt was falsified to be a candidate. But for the updated version, the original questions are still questions. Especially, `reset` and `shift` are still up to be implemented.**

Comment: does your update amount to an answer to your question? if so, maybe you could post it as such so the question no longer is considered unanswered?

Answer (score 2):

(This is not yet an answer, but only some clues came up in my mind. I hope this will lead to the real answer, by myself or by someone else.)

> [Call-by-Value is Dual to Call-by-Name](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/dual/dual.pdf) -- Philip Wadler

In the above paper the author introduced the "Dual Calculus", a typed calculus that is corresponding to the classical logic. In the last section, there is a segment says

> A strategy dual to call-by-need could
>   avoid this inefficiency by overwriting a coterm with its covalue
>   the first time it is evaluated.

As stated in Wadler's paper, call-by-name evaluating the continuations eagerly (it returns before all values being evaluated) whilst call-by-value evaluating the continuations lazily (it only returns after all values being evaluated).

Now, take a look at the `callCC'` above, I believe this is an example of the dual of call-by-need in the continuation side. The strategy of the evaluation, is that provide a fake "continuation" to the function given, but cache the state at this point to call the "true" continuation later on. This is somehow like making a cache of the continuation, and so once the computation finishes we restore that continuation. But cache the evaluated value is what it mean by call-by-need.

In general I suspect, state (computation up to the current point of time) is dual to continuation (the future computation). This will explain a few phenomenons. If this is true, it is not a surprise that `MonadRef` (correspond to a global and polymorphic state) is dual to `MoncadCont` (correspond to global and polymorphic continuations), and so they can be used to implement each other.