# MonadRef pure implementation

Tags: haskell, monads

I am researching on [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24237653/use-monadref-to-implement-monadcont) which related to `MonadRef`. When look at the definition

```
class MonadRef r m | m -> r where
    newRef :: a -> m (r a)
    readRef :: r a -> m a
    writeRef :: r a -> a -> m ()
```

I was thinking how to implement this with pure data structure but failed to find an answer. Actually, all the known standalone implementations (which does not depend on another `MonadRef`)

```
instance TVar STM
instance IORef IO
instance (STRef s) (ST s)
```

require `RealWorld` in pratise. Is that means we can only have `MonadRef`s that are not pure?

When I tried to resolve this, I first figure out that `Maybe` cannot implement `MonadRef` simply because it is too simple and there is no space for it to record the required information. As a generalise of this I conclude that for any implementation the `Monad` must be able to contain arbitrary number of information, simply because you can call `newRef` as many times as you can.

So I considered `[]` but it is still a fail because the data stored within the Monad can be of any type. I don't know how to construct a container in Haskell that can store any type of data whilst still have the ability to extract the data back with proper type (maybe [existential quantification](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/ExistentialQuantification) can help? But I still don't know how to do so).

Comment: Couldn't a State with a container and a counter for keys work?

Comment: @DanielWagner This depands how would you define "pure". According to the document it says "The s parameter is either an uninstantiated type variable (inside invocations of runST), or RealWorld (inside invocations of Control.Monad.ST.stToIO)", so it seems either options require some sort of "magic".

Comment: @EarthEngine Uninstantiated type variables aren't magic. And yes, you need some compiler support somewhere, but `ST` *is* that support.

Comment: @DanielWagner No... Uninstantiated type means you cannot specify what the actual type it should use, and the implementation select this for you. And if you read the implementation of `runST` you can see it uses `RealWorld` inside...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can *nearly* get there (implementing the equivalent of `ST` purely) by using a `State` monad with a state that is a `Map` dictionary from reference IDs to the value inside that reference.

But Haskell's type system lacks dependent types, in which the type of a value depends on the *value* of another term of fixed type.  Because of this, it cannot express that the type inside the reference depends on the reference's ID, in such a way that all types are allowed.

You can get around this by letting the values stored be of type `GHC.Exts.Any` and use
`Unsafe.Coerce.unsafeCoerce` to convert to the correct type internally.

But `unsafeCoerce` is, as advertised, unsafe.  This again means that Haskell's type system cannot give you any guarantees that you are using the references in a type safe way, and if you make an error you can get GHC to crash this way. (If `MonadRef` had had a `Data.Typeable.Typeable` constraint on its reference contents, that could have been used to do this, but it doesn't. (And you could then have put `Data.Dynamic.Dynamic` instead of `Any` inside the map.))

However, if you *do* use `unsafeCoerce` in this way nevertheless, taking care to hide the ID type used, and to implement the same API as `ST` does, including the `s` parameter which prevents different `ST` "threads" from confusing each other's references, then this should actually work safely as a library.  I found [at least one attempt on GitHub](https://github.com/pthariensflame/pure-st/blob/master/Control/Monad/ST/Pure.hs). (It also tries to work as a transformer, although I am suspicious of whether that is safe.)

Comment: For me, use `unsafeXXX` is cheating, just like that use `unsafePerformIO` and claim the function to be "pure". But if this is the only way to do things then we have to accept.

Comment: Sounds like the lack of a Typeable constraint and the lack of a functional dependency in the other direction are both important weaknesses with MonadRef. Perhaps a variation is called for?