# Why can't there be an instance of MonadFix for the continuation monad?

Tags: haskell, monads, continuation, monadfix

How can we prove that [the continuation monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Cont.html) has no valid instance of [`MonadFix`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Monad-Fix.html#t:MonadFix)?

Answer (score 7):

Well actually, it's not that there can't be a `MonadFix` instance, just that the library's type is a bit too constrained. If you define `ContT` over all possible `r`s, then not only does `MonadFix` become possible, but all instances up to `Monad` require nothing of the underlying functor :

```
newtype ContT m a = ContT { runContT :: forall r. (a -> m r) -> m r }
instance Functor (ContT m) where
  fmap f (ContT k) = ContT (\kb -> k (kb . f))
instance Monad (ContT m) where
  return a = ContT ($a)
  join (ContT kk) = ContT (\ka -> kk (\(ContT k) -> k ka))
instance MonadFix m => MonadFix (ContT m) where
  mfix f = ContT (\ka -> mfixing (\a -> runContT (f a) ka<&>(,a)))
    where mfixing f = fst <$> mfix (\ ~(_,a) -> f a )
```

Comment: It looks like your type is actually the more constrained one. Are there real situations where forcing the argument to `ContT` to be polymorphic would block useful implementations? If not, this is probably just a matter of history—`ContT` has been around for a long time, quite possibly before rank 2 types were a well-accepted part of Haskell.

Comment: Polymorphic argument `ContT` is also known as `Codensity`.  It lacks the ability to define `callCC`.

Comment: This answer explains why your `forall r. (a -> m r) -> m r` `ContT` can't have `callCC`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7180154/414413

Comment: Well, it's true that I can't define the `Control.Monad.Cont.callCC` with this definition of `Codensity` (thank you, Ørjan, for teaching me a new word :-) ), but if we use a typeclass that looks like Scheme's continuations, the instance almost writes itself : `class MonadCont m where callCC :: (forall b. (a -> m b) -> m b) -> m a`. We can use this instance in a way more consistent with the idea that we do not directly get a value in our continuation, but rather the rest of the computation to run with the value that we generate, of which we do not yet know the type (hence the `forall`).

Answer (score 2):

Consider the type signature of `mfix` for the continuation monad.

```hs
(a -> ContT r m a) -> ContT r m a

-- expand the newtype

(a -> (a -> m r) -> m r) -> (a -> m r) -> m r
```

Here's the proof that there's no pure inhabitant of this type.

```hs
---------------------------------------------
(a -> (a -> m r) -> m r) -> (a -> m r) -> m r

introduce f, k

f :: a -> (a -> m r) -> m r
k :: a -> m r
---------------------------
m r

apply k

f :: a -> (a -> m r) -> m r
k :: a -> m r
---------------------------
a

dead end, backtrack

f :: a -> (a -> m r) -> m r
k :: a -> m r
---------------------------
m r

apply f

f :: a -> (a -> m r) -> m r     f :: a -> (a -> m r) -> m r
k :: a -> m r                   k :: a -> m r
---------------------------     ---------------------------
a                               a -> m r

dead end                        reflexivity k
```

As you can see the problem is that both `f` and `k` expect a value of type `a` as an input. However, there's no way to conjure a value of type `a`. Hence, there's no pure inhabitant of `mfix` for the continuation monad.

Note that you can't define `mfix` recursively either because `mfix f k = mfix ? ?` would lead to an infinite regress since there's no base case. And, we can't define `mfix f k = f ? ?` or `mfix f k = k ?` because even with recursion there's no way to conjure a value of type `a`.

But, could we have an impure implementation of `mfix` for the continuation monad? Consider the following.

```hs
import Control.Concurrent.MVar
import Control.Monad.Cont
import Control.Monad.Fix
import System.IO.Unsafe

instance MonadFix (ContT r m) where
    mfix f = ContT $ \k -> unsafePerformIO $ do
        m <- newEmptyMVar
        x <- unsafeInterleaveIO (readMVar m)
        return . runContT (f x) $ \x' -> unsafePerformIO $ do
            putMVar m x'
            return (k x')
```

The question that arises is how to apply `f` to `x'`. Normally, we'd do this using a recursive let expression, i.e. `let x' = f x'`. However, `x'` is not the return value of `f`. Instead, the continuation given to `f` is applied to `x'`. To solve this conundrum, we create an empty mutable variable `m`, lazily read its value `x`, and apply `f` to `x`. It's safe to do so because `f` must not be strict in its argument. When `f` eventually calls the continuation given to it, we store the result `x'` in `m` and apply the continuation `k` to `x'`. Thus, when we finally evaluate `x` we get the result `x'`.

The above implementation of `mfix` for the continuation monad looks a lot like the implementation of `mfix` for the `IO` monad.

```hs
import Control.Concurrent.MVar
import Control.Monad.Fix

instance MonadFix IO where
    mfix f = do
        m <- newEmptyMVar
        x <- unsafeInterleaveIO (takeMVar m)
        x' <- f x
        putMVar m x'
        return x'
```

Note, that in the implementation of `mfix` for the continuation monad we used `readMVar` whereas in the implementation of `mfix` for the `IO` monad we used `takeMVar`. This is because, the continuation given to `f` can be called multiple times. However, we only want to store the result given to the first callback. Using `readMVar` instead of `takeMVar` ensures that the mutable variable remains full. Hence, if the continuation is called more than once then the second callback will block indefinitely on the `putMVar` operation.

However, only storing the result of the first callback seems kind of arbitrary. So, here's an implementation of `mfix` for the continuation monad that allows the provided continuation to be called multiple times. I wrote it in JavaScript because I couldn't get it to play nicely with laziness in Haskell.

```js
// mfix :: (Thunk a -> ContT r m a) -> ContT r m a
const mfix = f => k => {
    const ys = [];

    return (function iteration(n) {
        let i = 0, x;

        return f(() => {
            if (i > n) return x;
            throw new ReferenceError("x is not defined");
        })(y => {
            const j = i++;

            if (j === n) {
                ys[j] = k(x = y);
                iteration(i);
            }

            return ys[j];
        });
    }(0));
};

const example = triple => k => [
    { a: () => 1, b: () => 2, c: () => triple().a() + triple().b() },
    { a: () => 2, b: () => triple().c() - triple().a(), c: () => 5 },
    { a: () => triple().c() - triple().b(), b: () => 5, c: () => 8 },
].flatMap(k);

const result = mfix(example)(({ a, b, c }) => [{ a: a(), b: b(), c: c() }]);

console.log(result);
```

Here's the equivalent Haskell code, sans the implementation of `mfix`.

```hs
import Control.Monad.Cont
import Control.Monad.Fix

data Triple = { a :: Int, b :: Int, c :: Int } deriving Show

example :: Triple -> ContT r [] Triple
example triple = ContT $ \k ->
    [ Triple 1 2 (a triple + b triple)
    , Triple 2 (c triple - a triple) 5
    , Triple (c triple - b triple) 5 8
    ] >>= k

result :: [Triple]
result = runContT (mfix example) pure

main :: IO ()
main = print result
```

Notice that this looks a lot like the list monad.

```hs
import Control.Monad.Fix

data Triple = { a :: Int, b :: Int, c :: Int } deriving Show

example :: Triple -> [Triple]
example triple =
    [ Triple 1 2 (a triple + b triple)
    , Triple 2 (c triple - a triple) 5
    , Triple (c triple - b triple) 5 8
    ]

result :: [Triple]
result = mfix example

main :: IO ()
main = print result
```

This makes sense because after all the continuation monad is [the mother of all monads](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/the-mother-of-all-monads). I'll leave the verification of the `MonadFix` laws of my JavaScript implementation of `mfix` as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: That proof is not convincing in this particular setting because it only considers implementation without recursion, whereas recursion is the very point of `MonadFix`.

Comment: This `MonadFix` instance for `ContT` breaks referential transparency: the value of `x` depends on whether or not the continuation is called, which depends on evaluation order, even if it is applied at most once.

Comment: On the other hand, if you embrace the unsafety, it could be a fun way to tie knots.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia You can't define `mfix` recursively either because `mfix f k = mfix ? ?` would lead to an infinite regress since there's no base case. And, we can't define `mfix f k = f ? ?` or `mfix f k = k ?` because even with recursion there's no way to conjure a value of type `a`.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia True. It does break referential transparency.